# ListView displaying incorrect title

Tags: android, xml, listview, rss

I have a simple application that pulls an `XML` file from pc worlds `RSS` feed here:

**http://feeds.pcworld.com/pcworld/latestnews**

I want to display the name of the titles in a `ListView` then when the user selects one the article opens up in a browser window.

The application is working the only thing is that the title is not being displayed correctly in the ListView.

It should be something like this:

**Make you website stand out with Windows 8**

But instead it is this:

**com.example.simplerss.Item@424b9998**

Any ideas?

This is my code for the `MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

ArrayAdapter<Item> adapter;
List<Item>items;//Holds item objects containing info relating to element pulled from XML file.
Item item;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //initialize variables
    items = new ArrayList<Item>();

    new PostTask().execute();

    adapter=  new ArrayAdapter<Item>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    setListAdapter(adapter);        

}

private InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {
    try{
        return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
    }catch(IOException e){
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Uri uri = items.get(position).getLink();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

//ASYNC CLASS
private class PostTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        try{
            //link to data source
            URL url = new URL("http://feeds.pcworld.com/pcworld/latestnews");


            //Set up parser
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

            //get XML from input stream
            InputStream in = getInputStream(url);
            if (in == null) {
                throw new Exception("Empty inputstream");
            }
            xpp.setInput(in, "UTF_8");

            //Keep track of which tag inside of XML
            boolean insideItem = false;

            //Loop through the XML file and extract data required
            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

                if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    Log.v("ENTER", String.valueOf(xpp.getEventType()));

                    if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                        insideItem = true;

                        //Create new item object
                        item = new Item();

                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                        if (insideItem){
                            item.setTitle(xpp.nextText());
                            Log.i("title", item.getTitle());
                        }

                    } 

                    else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {
                        if (insideItem){
                            item.setDescription(xpp.nextText());
                        }
                    }

                    else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                        if (insideItem){
                            item.setLink(Uri.parse(xpp.nextText()));                            
                        }
                    }
                }else if(eventType==XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")){

                    insideItem=false;
                    //add item to list
                    items.add(item);

                }


                eventType = xpp.next(); //move to next element
                publishProgress();
            }


                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
                catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }


        return "COMPLETED";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    public void onPostExecute(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s + " Items: " + items.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

}

and for the `Item` Class

```
public class Item {

//Variables
private String title;
private Uri link;
private String description;

public Item() {
    super();
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
public Uri getLink() {
    return link;
}
public void setLink(Uri link) {
    this.link = link;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the `toString()` method in `Item`.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return title;
}
```

This should solve your problem.
Right now, the ArrayAdapter sets its View's texts to Item.toString(), but this is the default method of Object that returns the Object's ID. With overriding it, you give it a meaningful value, in your case the title.

Comment: thanks that fixed it! Will accept in 2 mins when I am allowed

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem lies in:

```
else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
        if (insideItem){
            item.setTitle(xpp.nextText());
            Log.i("title", item.getTitle());
        }
}
```

Here, `getName()` is a method from the Java [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29) object.  The method you want is [readContent()](http://www.extreme.indiana.edu/xgws/xsoap/xpp/download/PullParser2/doc/api/org/gjt/xpp/XmlPullParser.html#readContent%28%29) I think.  I haven't used this library so that may not be exactly correct but you can certainly find what you need in the [docs](http://www.extreme.indiana.edu/xgws/xsoap/xpp/download/PullParser2/doc/api/).